# How to avoid 'invalid command' error when building Linux kernel on Fedora 28?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm building a Linux kernel on Fedora 28, but always run into the same error such as:

```
CC      init/main.o  
init/main.o: warning: objtool: elf_begin: invalid command  
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:277: init/main.o] Error 1  
make[1]: *** Deleting file 'init/main.o'  
make: *** [Makefile:1067: init] Error 2  
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

I tried "linux-5.0.16.tar.gz" and "linux-5.0.21.tar.gz" downloaded from [kernel.org](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/)

, and also tried to follow the instruction on [Fedora wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Building_a_custom_kernel)

But there is no way to avoid this 'invalid command' error. "elfutils-libelf-devel" and "elfutils-libelf" are installed. In the fedora way, 'fedpkg cone -a kernel' was successful, so all dependences are installed. Does anyone know what is missing?

Further progress:
The same procedure works on a different machine installed with Fedora 30.
However, after upgrading the original machine to Fedora 30, the error persists.

Comment: Fedora28.updates, kernel-5.0.16-100.fc28 source package https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/updates/28/Everything/SRPMS/Packages/k/kernel-5.0.16-100.fc28.src.rpm → → comes with 16 scripts, 47 patches : (1. May contain a fix for your issues.) ... **2.** Why not build a Fedora 28 `kernel-5.0.16-1xx.fc28` **.rpm** : Edit config script, and run `$ rpmbuild -bb kernel.spec`

Comment: I tried the same steps on Fedora 30, and it seems to work. On Fedora 28 with Kernel: Linux 5.0.16-100.fc28.x86_64, the problem still occurs.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the changes you have made. And please explain the reason to build a special version.

Answer (score 0):

The machine with the 'invalid command' problem had an old version of libelf.so installed under /user/local. After removing the old libelf, objtool is linked to the current libelf library, and is able to run during compilation of the linux kernel.

A comment is found in the linux source code /tools/perf/util/symbols.h:

/*
 * libelf 0.8.x and earlier do not support ELF_C_READ_MMAP;
 * for newer versions we can use mmap to reduce memory usage:
 */

This comment led me to look for an out-dated version of libelf.